# get_theme_mod only returns false

Tags: theme-customizer, options, get-theme-mod

I have created a custom section with a setting with one control allowing users to choose fonts from a dropdown. However, when I use the get_theme_mod() function, and echo the results to a styles tag in the header, I get nothing.

The debugger tells me that get_theme_mod() is returning 'false', when I expect it to return the value of the selected item. Using get_option() gives me the key of the option, "value3" and not the value.

I would prefer to use get_theme_mod() since that is what the function is for, but if I can't how do I get it to output 'American Typewriter' instead of "value3"?

**functions.php**

```
function lettra_customized_css()
{
 ?>
  <style type='text/css'>
    .site-title {
      <?php 
      $foo = get_option('title_font'); // "value3"
      $bar = get_theme_mod('title_font');// false
      ?>font-family: <?php echo get_theme_mod('title_font') ?>;
    }
  </style>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'lettra_customized_css');
```

**cutomizer.php**

```
function lettra_customize_register($wp_customize)
{
  $wp_customize->add_section(
    'font_options',
    array(
      'title'       => __('Font Options', 'lettra'), //Visible title of section
      'priority'    => 20, //Determines what order this appears in
      'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options', //Capability needed to tweak
      'description' => __('Choose font pairings for your theme here.', 'lettra'), //Descriptive tooltip
)
  );

  $wp_customize->add_setting('title_font', array(
    'default'        => 'Roboto Slab',
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
    'type'           => 'option',
    'transport'  => 'postMessage'
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_control('title_font_control', array(
    'label'      => __('Title Font', 'lettra'),
    'section'    => 'font_options',
    'settings'   => 'title_font',
    'type'       => 'select',
    'choices'    => array(
      'value1' => 'Roboto Slab',
      'value2' => 'Times New Roman',
      'value3' => 'American Typewriter',
    ),
  ));
}
add_action('customize_register', 'lettra_customize_register');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The debugger tells me that get_theme_mod() is returning 'false', when
>   I expect it to return the value of the selected item.

`get_theme_mod()` isn't working because when you registered the setting, you set the `type` to `option`:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('title_font', array(
  'default'        => 'Roboto Slab',
  'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
  'type'           => 'option',
  'transport'  => 'postMessage'
));
```

The possible values for `type` when adding a setting are `'option'`, or the default, `'theme_mod'`.

`option` stores the value independently of the current theme, and is retrieved with `get_option()`, while `theme_mod` stores the value only for the current theme, and is retrieved with `get_theme_mod()`.

> Using get_option() gives me the key of the option, "value3" and not the value.

The 'key' *is* the value. It's what's output into the `value=""` attribute of the `<option>` tag.

If you want to use the label, there's two potential solutions.

First, you could just pass the labels only, then these will also be used as the values:

```
array(
  'Roboto Slab',
  'Times New Roman',
  'American Typewriter',
),
```

Or you could store a reference to the labels independently of both places:

```
function wpse_341193_get_font_options() {
    return array(
      'value1' => 'Roboto Slab',
      'value2' => 'Times New Roman',
      'value3' => 'American Typewriter',
    );
}
```

Which you can then use as the choices:

```
'choices' => wpse_341193_get_font_options(),
```

And the output:

```
<?php
$font_options = wpse_341193_get_font_options();
$font_family  = get_theme_mod('title_font');// false
?>font-family: <?php echo $font_options[$font_family] ?>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, especially explaining that the key is the value!

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: `get_option` instead of `get_theme_mod`.

How you store and retrieve value depends on the type you pass to your `add_setting` function. 
See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_setting.
If you want to use `get_theme_mod`, type should be `theme_mod`, which is default.

Problem 2: getting value instead of label.

When you are passing choices to `add_control` function, this is an array with combination of `value => label`. Hence the value part will be used to store in DB, and to retrieve later on. 
To use `Label` to store in DB, you can pass normal array, or use label as value.

```
'choices'    => array(
  'Roboto Slab' => 'Roboto Slab',
  'Times New Roman' => 'Times New Roman',
  'American Typewriter' => 'American Typewriter',
),
```

OR

```
'choices'    => array(
  'Roboto Slab',
  'Times New Roman',
  'American Typewriter',
),
```

Hope this helps.